# Size of square formed by soap in a cube frame

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, mathematical-physics

So through the work of Plateau (as I understand it), we know that soap tries to find the shortest connection between points. At least, that's what I was taught. With this in mind, I had to solve the following problem:

> In a cube frame with sides of length 20cm, soap forms a square, at half height in the center of the cube (*Don't know how to properly translate this into English)*. Calculate the area of the square in $cm^2$.

So, first of all to give you an idea of what is meant here:

[image]

So this is a sketch I made to solve this problem:

[image]
So we want the distance between the vertices of the square and the vertices of the cube to be minimal. So I thought that the total distance would equal:

$$8\sqrt{x^2 + 100} + 4(20-2x)$$

So we want this to be as small as possible, take the derivative and make it equal zero: $$ \dfrac{8x}{\sqrt{x^2+100}} - 8 = 0$$

But this doesn't have a solution. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't know physics, but I'd *guess* the surface area, not lengths, would be minimized.

Comment: @msh210 that might be true too, but I would still not know how to do the problem.

Comment: If you assure me it *is* true, then perhaps I can work the problem. `:-)` Don't worry: probably someone who knows both the physics and the math will post an answer.

Comment: @msh210 These are his laws: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau's_laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know for this is that, when three soap films meet along an edge, the mutual angles are $120^\circ.$

Among many, I can [recommend this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486269604) and, [probably, this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np9TuarsoX8) by the author.

EDIT: he does your soap film at about minute 23. It is not a real square! I will leave this here... Alright, this requires that the faces that resemble flat trapezoids are not really planar, either. So the whole thing is not as it first appears.

Comment: Surely the in-plane height of the trapezoid has to be greater than $10$. Also, the dihedral angles between the *planes* are $120^\circ$, but the angles in the trapezoid I'm not sure. [Shouldn't those be more like $109.5^\circ$?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_molecular_geometry)

Comment: So we get two 30-60-90 triangles?

Comment: @Rahul, on the one hand, this drawing is a side-on view. Second, it is not a real square...

Comment: @Phaptitude, well, not really, not a real square....

Comment: @WillJagy I don't understand what you mean. First of all, this is a high school problem, so yes, this is probably not even a realistic scenario, but this is a problem in my booklet. I highly doubt it is harder than it first seems, it is just an ideal (or, as you've proven, non-realistic) scenario where a square is formed. Seeing as the 2 upper angles of the trapezoids are 120 degrees, shouldn't the 2 lower be 60 degrees, hence creating 2 30-60-90 triangles (and a rectangle)?

Comment: @Phaptitude, if that is what they want, then work with 30-60-90 triangles. But also show the video link to your teacher. More detail is given in his book, pages 84-85, discussing color Plate 4.4.